# How to join a table that has no relationship to its parent tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have the following schema:

```
-- table 1
__________
|   id    |
|   1000  |
|   1001  |
|   1002  |
|   1003  |

-- table 2
______________________
|  id  |   fk_table_1 |
|  100 |       1000   |
|  101 |       1000   |
|  102 |       1000   |
|  103 |       1000   |
|  104 |       1001   |


-- table 3
_______________________________
|  id  |   source  |   target  |
|  1   |    100    |    101    |
|  2   |    102    |    103    |
```

I need to pull out all the `table 3` records that are relevant to `table 1` and `table 2`. The problem here is that `table 3` has no relationship to the other tables.

How can I join these tables?

The desired output would be something like:

```
relations: [
    {
        id: '1',
        source: '100',
        target: '101'
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        source: '102',
        target: '103'
    },
]
```

This array must contain all `table 2` records that are related to `table 1`, in this case, the result is linked to the record with id `1000` from `table 1`.

I've tried doing,

```
SELECT
     tb3.id,
     tb3.source,
     tb3.target
FROM table_3 tb3
LEFT JOIN table_1 tb1 ON tb1.id = 1000
LEFT JOIN table_2 tb2 ON tb2.fk_table_1 = tb1.id
```

But this just returns all records from `table 3`.

Comment: please share desired output

Comment: I've edited the post.

Comment: So you want to convert the content of table3 to a JSON String?

Comment: Yes, I need to return it to the frontend.

Comment: What makes you say the table 3 has no relationship to the others? It very much looks like it does. Isn't source and target the table2.id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you just want to show table3 rows where source and target are linked to table1.id = 1000.

You can join

```
select t3.*
from table3 t3
join table2 t2s on t2s.id = t3.source and t2s.fk_table_1 = 1000
join table2 t2t on t2t.id = t3.target and t2t.fk_table_1 = 1000;
```

or use `IN` (which I prefer, because we only want to select table3 rows for which a condition applies, and conditions belong in the `WHERE` clause, not in the `FROM` clause in my opinion)

```
select *
from table3
where source in (select id from table2 where fk_table_1 = 1000)
  and target in (select id from table2 where fk_table_1 = 1000);
```

If it suffices that source *or* target are linked to t1.id 1000, then the second query can be easily amended by changing `AND` to `OR`. (The first query would need more amendment, i.e. changing inner to outer joins and applying a combined `WHERE` clause.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `json_agg` with `json_build_object`:

```
select json_agg(json_build_object('id', t3.id, 'source', t3.source, 'target', t3.target, 'fk_table_1', t2.fk_table_1)) 
from table3 t3 join table2 t2 on t3.source = t2.id where t2.fk_table_id = 1000
```

Output:

```
[{"id" : 1, "source" : 100, "target" : 101, "fk_table_1" : 1000}, {"id" : 2, "source" : 102, "target" : 103, "fk_table_1" : 1000}]
```